# Remove extra sign-in step after enabling Forms Based Authentication

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, forms-authentication

Now that I have enabled Forms Based Authentication (FBA) on my sharepoint site, there is an extra Sign-In page where I have to select what type of authentication I wish to use. I pretty much want users to only use FBA. Therefore this step is redundant.

If I disable "Windows Authentication" in the "Edit Authentication" menu in Central Admin, it states that my site will no longer be able to be crawled. I obviously still want my site to be searchable.

So how do I remove this extra Sign-In step without removing Windows Authentication?

[image: Extra Sign-In Step]

Answer (score 4):

Extend the Web Application to create two zones - one can be Windows Authentication only, that will allow your content to be crawled. The second can be FBA only, allowing the users to login directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom login page that changes the functionality.  Here is an example:  http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2011/06/23/sharepoint-2010-custom-login-page/